# React component placeholder

Tags: css, reactjs, components

I've got this component in react:

```
<div className={"form-group "+ this.props.className}>
    <label
        className="control-label"
    >
        {Translation.getPhrase(this.props.label)}
    </label>
    {this.props.children}
</div>
```

I returns a column with a label as Header. Now I want it to return a column with the exact same height if I don't specify the label-property. If I just set a label without a value in it react won't display it.

Comment: have you tried passing a white space character like ' ' ?

Comment: You could also set a min:height to the div.

Comment: @Palisanka Unfortunately that doesn't work

Comment: @CataJohn won't work because then the other controls would display at the top of the div